# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory and then the browser just shows nothing

Tags: node.js, linux

when I node express_serer.js it was fine but then when I try to go to 52.37.213.112:3000/nearbysearch
the browser says 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/ubuntu/mymap./templates/nearby_search.html'

below is my code and folder structure, thank you so much.

```
`   var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');

var GOOGLE_KEY = 'AIzaSyCqpCymNwYEAjc-U46Clz9mUHz0KJNhzoM';
var okaces_url =       'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/nearbysearch', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + './templates/nearby_search.html'));
});

app.get('/places-info', function(req, api_res){
    var radius = req.query.radius ? req.query.radius : 150;
    var params = {
        'key': GOOGLE_KEY,
        'location': req.query.lat + ',' + req.query.lng,
        'radius': radius,
        'type': req.query.type
    };
    request({url: places_url, qs: params}, function(err, res, body) {
        if (res.statusCode == 200){
            console.log(body)
            api_res.json(body)
        }
    });
});

app.use('/css', express.static('css'))
app.use('/js', express.static('js'))

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('app started on port 3000');
});`
```

now I can reach the address without error but the browser just shows nothing.Is it something about my css file?

Comment: Please include the code here instead of posting images. I don't see `nearby_structure.html` in your directory structure

Comment: You have a typo; it should be `/template/` not `./templates/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
path.join(__dirname + './templates/nearby_search.html')
```

inside your `/nearbysearch` route

Change it to

```
path.join(__dirname, 'template/nearby_search.html')
```

**Explanation**

`'/home/ubuntu/mymap./templates/nearby_search.html'` is not a valid path and you have it because you concatenated `__dirname` with your relative path. You didn't use `path.join` as it should be used. Just pass it "parts" of the path you want to create and it will concatenate them properly as I have shown at the top.

Comment: I have changed to your answer while it shows the same error. Thanks a lot

Comment: @QIANCHU try again with the typo fix

Comment: Now it's working but my browser shows nothing, is it something wrong about the css file? Also, thanks a lot the code works

Comment: well that is a different question and it may be a few things including css but without any code I can't tell.

Comment: @QIANCHU if this answers your question please accept it as correct